# Elastica Facet Range

Tags: symfony, elastica

I have problem by creating query for elastica,it looks like this

```
$finder = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.finder.website.product');
$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();

$fieldText = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
$fieldText->setFieldQuery('name', $keyword);
$fieldText->setFieldParam('name', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
$boolQuery->addMust($fieldText);//`enter code here

$fieldTerms = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();//`enter code here`enter code here`
$fieldTerms->setTerms('taxon_ids', $themeArray);//`enter code here`
$boolQuery->addMust($fieldTerms);


//But when I add Facets range it makes problem?Any Help?`enter code here`

 if(count($priceRange))
 {
 $facets = new \Elastica\Facet\Range('price');
 $facets->setField('price');
 $facets->addRange($min, $max);
 $facets->setGlobal(false);
 $query->addFacet($facets);
 }


 $resultSet = $finder->find($query, 500);///It brokes here?
```

Please can anybody help me with this query, I am using FOSElasticaBundle?

Comment: Was I able to help? Did you solve the problem? If you have any more Q's, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done exactly what you are doing BUT I would guess you need to use the `\Elastica\Search` class, then create and send a query to that. Something like:

```
$searcher = new \Elastica\Search( put-your-client-here! );

$esResultSet = $searcher->search($query);

$arrayOfResults = $esResultSet->getResults();
$arrayOfFacets =  $esResultSet->getFacets();
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ok but it retuns some elastica results, I need my objects as finder returns, how can I get real object from this getResults?